# Send image link via Express and display with EJS

Tags: image, express, ejs

I am trying to make a quiz app and I am using the MEAN stack.
my server will send an object containing details pertaining to the questions - answers, image, question text. I wish to send a link to the ejs file which will then display the image referenced by that link. 
I googled around to find some material on this issue but was unable to find any which address this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few different method and the one below worked:
1) Add the link to the image in the object to be passed by the server

```
var objCard = {
    QuestionText:"What is the indicated sign?",
    ImageLink: "/assets/images/dummy.jpg"
}
```

2) Inside the ejs file use *<%= %>* from within the img tag

```
<img src="<%= objCard.ImageLink %>">
```